# Looping through every starred file in my Drive folder and running a macro. No bugs but script not working...why?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote the following script that looks through every starred file in Google Drive and executes two functions. The problem is, the functions are not actually doing their thing in the files. I'm new to scripting so any help or insight helps!

```
function runMacroOnStarredFiles(folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder()) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    if(file.isStarred() && file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS) {
      SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheets().forEach(sh => {
        if(sh.getName() !== null) {
          Newrowmacro();//the macro
    function Newrowmacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('19:19').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A19').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=TODAY()');
  spreadsheet.getRange('H19').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=TODAY()');
  spreadsheet.getRange('M19').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=TODAY()');
  spreadsheet.getRange('A19').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBorder(null, null, null, true, null, null, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  spreadsheet.getRange('E22').activate();
};
        }
      });
    }
  }
  const subfolders = folder.getFolders()
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    let subfolder = subfolders.next();
    runMacroOnStarredFiles(subfolder);
  }
}
```

Comment: where do you *call* these functions? also, afaik enternewrow() is *inside* of a while loop, which means it can only be called *inside that code block*. also you don't need to get `sheet` in the while loop since you never use it, and you also don't do anything inside the while loop except for define the same function each time

Comment: @Esther, thank you! I made some changes to the script. I'm learning as I go - so it seems I defined the functions but never told the script to execute them? What I want this script to do is open a starred sheet in Drive, execute enternewrow, execute runalltabs, then move on to the next starred sheet and repeat until the last one is complete. If you can share guidance on how I would call these functions and in what segment of the script that should happen I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

#### Run macro on all Starred Files

```
function runMacroOnStarredFiles(folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder()) {
  Logger.log(folder.getName());
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
    if (file.isStarred() && file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS) {
      SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheets().forEach(sh => {
        enternewrow();//the macro
      });
    }
  }
  const subfolders = folder.getFolders()
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    let subfolder = subfolders.next();
    runMacroOnStarredFiles(subfolder);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper! I copied your script in and added the macro where you designated but I'm getting an error "Attempted to execute runMacroOnStarredFiles, but could not save" citing line 11 , which is right under function enternewrow(). I updated the script above - did I input the macro wrong?

Comment: It saves fine for me.  Only you can determine if you saved it correctly.

Comment: I recreated the macro and it's working now! But it's adding two rows instead of one. Does your script also run the macro in every tab within every file?

Comment: Actually every time I run it, it adds a different number of rows, and it also doesn't appear to be affecting all starred files. Updated above with the latest iteration. Is anything off?

Comment: I believe the code runs the every sheet of every starred spreadsheet in your drive.

Comment: I added some Logger.logs to the script to record folder and file names